# EF Core fluent api configurations on different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-fluent-api

I have two projects, `Data` and `Domain`. In `Data` I have the Fluent API, I want to move it's contents to `Domain`. How can I do this? Is there a way to configure EF to make this if I'm using a database-first approach?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Student", "dbo");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
                      .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsEnabled)
                      .IsRequired()
                      .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                      .HasMaxLength(250);

                entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedDate)
                      .HasColumnType("datetime");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the configuration of the `Student` entity to the `Domain` project into a separate class implemententing [`IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ientitytypeconfiguration-1).

> Allows configuration for an entity type to be factored into a separate class, rather than in-line in OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder).

```
public class StudentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable("Student", "dbo");
            
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");
        
        // More rules go here.
    }
}
```

---

In your `DbContext` you load the configurations from the `Domain` project, like below for example.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(Student).Assembly);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: do I have to make this process manually for the rest of entities?

Comment: It's a manual thing to go through, yes. You need a `IEntityTypeConfiguration` for each entity. `OnModelCreating` just needs 1 such `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` call for the `Domain` assembly.

Comment: after making the changes I'm getting an error on  public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
        {
            //we do  track the changes to entities retrived from the database into context
            this.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        }
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Campign' of type 'ICollection<Campaign>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: That will not be related to the split into `IEntityTypeConfiguration` instances, but rather to a property configuration that is not correct; your error says `the property configuration for  Campign of type ICollection<Campaign>`. You'll have to work on getting that one in place.